# angular ui router - using the same templateUrl and controller multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I am using the AngularUI Router framework for the first time and wondered how I could improve the below code.

Basically this all works fine but eventually (in the project I am working on) there will be 20 questions or more and I dont want to state the same 'templateUrl' & 'controller' for every state.

The below is a slimmed down version of what I mean:

**index.html**

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

**questions.html**

```
<a ui-sref="q1">q1</a>
<a ui-sref="q2">q2</a>

<div ng-show="$state.current.name === 'q1'">q1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere.</div> 

<div ng-show="$state.current.name === 'q2'">q2. Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</div>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('foo', ['ui.router'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider

    .state('q1', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'questions.html',
        controller: 'questionsCtrl'
    })

    .state('q2', {
        url: '/q2',
        templateUrl: 'questions.html',
        controller: 'questionsCtrl'   
    });     

})

.controller('questionsCtrl', function($scope, $state) {

    $scope.$state = $state;

});

;
```

I would like to follow best practice and keep the app.js as small/manageable as possible.

Cheers

Comment: How is it possible that they use the same templateUrl/controller if they are different questions?

Comment: you are really approaching this in the wrong way, but it's a very in depth topic that deserves more than a single post.  I set up a chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60150/angular-js-routing-discussion if you want to discuss what you are doing.

Comment: @Wawy Because the questions are coming from a json and are in a big ng-repeat (ive stripped it down for ease) Having a url for each question is needed for when people click back or need a link to a specific q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of discussion in chat, we were able to build a functional [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yDrASARnN5mY8S9qWmC1?p=preview) using state parameters.

html:

```
<a ui-sref="question({questionID:'q1'})">q1</a>
<a ui-sref="question({questionID:'q2'})">q2</a>

{{questionID}}

<div ng-show="questionID == 'q1'">q1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere.</div> 

<div ng-show="questionID == 'q2'">q2. Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</div>
```

app.js:

```
.state('question', {
        url: '/:questionID',
        templateUrl: 'questions.html',
        controller: 'questionsCtrl'
})

.controller('questionsCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    
    //$scope.$state = $state;
    $scope.questionID = $stateParams.questionID;
    
});
```

transcript of the chat is at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/60150

Answer (score 2):

Just use URL parameters as described here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters

You can then have a state such as:

```
.state('question', {
    url: '/:questionID',
    templateUrl: 'questions.html',
    controller: 'questionsCtrl'   
});
```

You can access the `questionID` using `$stateParams` which you need to inject into your controller.